# How not to let to choose older months in jquery datebox

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following HTML code

`<input type="date" value="" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="texto" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' readonly/>`

and I would like to let to choose a date only from the actual date in advance. How can I remove the previous months and years? for example, if the actual date is in April, the user wouldn't have the "previous month" button for going to a previous month for choosing a day in March...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, the HTML code is this <input type="date" value="" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="texto" onchange="javascript: comprobarFechas('startDate'); calcularNoches();" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' readonly/>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://dev.sainte-marine.org/mobile-datebox/demos/android/#/mobile-datebox/demos/android/limit.html and let us know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link and sorry for not answering before. It's a good solution but it doesn't work in my case. I'm using "mode": "calbox" instead of "mode": "datebox" Any suggestion about that? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi again, I was taking a look again and i found this option "afterToday": true which works great. Thanks for your help